# Issue with MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, mysql-5.6

My problem is that windows services don't have MySQL Server. How to run it?

I need to run MySQL Server on a new for me laptop. There's Windows 7. And MySQL have been installed on it. In order to verify this, I opened the `Programs and Features` window and saw it there:

[image: Programs and Features]

But when I go to the `Services` to run it, I don't find it. It's absent there:

[image]

It's very strange for me. Why MySQL is not among the services? How can I run it? It's installed on this station.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the following steps and then check again.

1. Start Command Prompt (cmd)
2. Go to the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
3. type mysqld --install

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed it through [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) so I do not have it among windows services (it has it´s own control panel), but I found this document that may help you solve this problem:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html

Also check the error log file which shows specific information about the start and stop of the service. In my case is called mysql_error.log and it is located under the '...mysql\data\' folder. Another document talking about that:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html